# Minimizing linear least squares using Lagrangian $L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1)$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, machine-learning, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares

Section **4.5 Example: Linear Least Squares** of the textbook *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, says the following:

> Suppose we want to find the value of $\mathbf{x}$ that minimizes
>
> $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \dfrac{1}{2}||\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}||_2^2 \tag{4.21}$$
>
> Specialized linear algebra algorithms can solve this problem efficiently; however, we can also explore how to solve it using gradient-based optimization as a simple example of how these techniques work.
>
> First, we need to obtain the gradient:
>
> $$\nabla_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}^T (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}) = \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b} \tag{4.22}$$
>
> We can then follow this gradient downhill, taking small steps. See algorithm 4.1 for details.
>
> ---
>
> **Algorithm 4.1** An algorithm to minimise $f(\mathbf{x}) = \dfrac{1}{2}||\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}||_2^2$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ using gradient descent, starting form an arbitrary value of $\mathbf{x}$.
>
> ---
>
> Set the step size ($\epsilon$) and tolerance ($\delta$) to small, positive numbers.
>
> **while** $||\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b}||_2 > \delta$ **do**
>
> $\ \ \ \mathbf{x} \leftarrow \mathbf{x} - \epsilon(\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b})$
>
> **end while**
>
> ---
>
> One can also solve this problem using Newton's method. In this case, because the true function is quadratic, the quadratic approximation employed by Newton's method is exact, and the algorithm converges to the global minimum in a single step.
>
> Now suppose we wish to minimize the same function, but subject to the constraint $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} \le 1$. To do so, we introduce the Lagrangian
>
> $$L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1). \tag{4.23}$$
>
> We can now solve the problem
>
> $$\min_{x} \max_{\lambda, \lambda \ge 0} L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda). \tag{4.24}$$
>
> The smallest-norm solution to the unconstrained least-squares problem may be found using the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse: $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^+ \mathbf{b}$. If this point is feasible, then it is the solution to the constrained problem. Otherwise, we must find a solution where the constraint is active. By differentiating the Lagrangian with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, we obtain the equation
>
> $$\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b} + 2 \lambda \mathbf{x} = 0 \tag{4.25}$$
>
> This tells us that the solution will take the form
>
> $$\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A} + 2 \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{b} \tag{4.26}$$
>
> The magnitude $\lambda$ must be chosen such that the result obeys the constraints. We can find this value by performing gradient ancient on $\lambda$. To do so, observe
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{\lambda}} L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1 \tag{4.27}$$
>
> When the norm of $\mathbf{x}$ exceeds $1$, this derivative is positive, so to follow the derivative uphill and increase the Lagrangian with respect to $\lambda$, we increase $\lambda$. Because the coefficient on the $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}$ penalty has increased, solving the linear equation for $\mathbf{x}$ will now yield a solution with a smaller norm. The process of solving the linear equation and adjusting $\lambda$ continues until $\mathbf{x}$ has the correct norm and the derivative is $0$.

I've been wondering why the Lagrangian was chosen to take the form $L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1)$? Given the expression, it was obviously constructed this way intentionally, but I wonder what the reasoning was for using this Lagrangian?

I would appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

---

### **EDIT:**

My understanding is that the term $\lambda (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1)$ in $L(\mathbf{x}, \lambda) = f(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1)$ is the penalty. So the question is really one that revolves around penalties, and why the penalty $\lambda (\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - 1)$ was chosen for $f(\mathbf{x})$. So I think part of what I am misunderstanding here is the concept of penalties.

Comment: One way to motivate the Lagrangian is that we are attempting to replace the constraint $x^T x -1 \leq 0$ with a penalty term $\lambda (x^T x - 1)$. The penalty is positive only if the constraint is violated. It's hard to think of a simpler penalty function than this one that would encourage our constraint to be satisfied.

Comment: @littleO That's an interesting way of thinking about it. But this then begs the question: why are we using the constraint $x^T x -1 \leq 0$?

Comment: The constraint $x^T x \leq 1$ was introduced just as an example of a different optimization problem that we might want to solve (in some particular application). The book is just saying, ok, that's how we solve a standard least squares problem, now what if we had a different optimization problem that included a constraint such a $x^T x \leq 1$? How would we handle such a constraint? Constrained optimization problems like this come up every now and then in various applications.

Comment: Constraints can't be handled directly by gradient descent. The strategy behind Lagrange multipliers is to replace a constrained problem with an unconstrained problem. If we somehow knew the correct value of the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$, then solving our original constrained problem would be equivalent to minimizing $f(x) + \lambda (x^T x-1)$, with no constraints on $x$. Presumably this unconstrained problem would be easier to solve.

Comment: When we talk about neural networks the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector of neural network weights. The very popular technique to improve the quality of the learning process is to apply **max norm constraints**: $\| \mathbf{x} \|_2 < c$ or $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} < c$ or $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} - c < 0$.

The typical values for $c$ is 2 or 3. But 1 also a good value. See, for example, [keras documentation][1] for MaxNorm constraint.


  [1]: https://keras.io/constraints/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Version**

It can be interpreted as follows by using the saddle-point property or the strong max-min property.

We want to solve the following convex optimization problem:
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, \ x^Tx \le 1} \tfrac{1}{2}(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b). \tag{1}$$
If $(A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b\le 1$, clearly $x_0 = A^{+}b$ is the solution where $A^{+}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse. 
In the following, we assume that $(A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b > 1$.

Denote $f(x) = \tfrac{1}{2}(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$. First, clearly, we have
\begin{align}
\sup_{\lambda \ge 0} [f(x) + \lambda (x^Tx - 1)] = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                                                            f(x) & x^Tx \le 1 \\[3pt]
                                                            +\infty & x^Tx > 1.
                                                          \end{array}
\right. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Thus, we have
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, \ x^Tx \le 1} f(x) = \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \sup_{\lambda \ge 0} [f(x) + \lambda (x^Tx - 1)]. \tag{3}$$
Denote $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda (x^Tx - 1)$.
Clearly, $L(x, \lambda)$ is a convex function of $x$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each fixed $\lambda \ge 0$,
and a concave (indeed, affine) function of $\lambda$ on $[0, +\infty)$ for each fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
From exercise 3.14 in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujpgV.png) (page 115), if there exists $(x^\ast, \lambda^\ast)$ with $\lambda^\ast \ge 0$ such
that $\nabla L(x^\ast, \lambda^\ast) = 0$ where
\begin{align}
\nabla L(x, \lambda) = \left(
                         \begin{array}{c}
                           \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \\[5pt]
                           \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} \\
                         \end{array}
                       \right) = \left(
                                   \begin{array}{c}
                                     (A^TA + 2\lambda I)x - A^Tb \\[4pt]
                                     x^Tx - 1 \\
                                   \end{array}
                                 \right), \tag{4}
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
&\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \sup_{\lambda \ge 0} L(x, \lambda)
= \sup_{\lambda \ge 0} \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} L(x, \lambda) = L(x^\ast, \lambda^\ast) = f(x^\ast). \tag{5}
\end{align}
From (3) and (5), $x^\ast$ is the solution to the problem (1). 
As a result, any $(x^\ast, \lambda^\ast)$ with $\lambda^\ast \ge 0$ satisfying $\nabla L(x^\ast, \lambda^\ast) = 0$ gives the solution $x^\ast$ to the problem of (1).

Thus, we turn to solve the system of equations $\nabla L(x, \lambda) = 0$.
To this end, we give the following result (the proof is given later):

*Fact 1*: If $(A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b > 1$, then there exists $\lambda^\ast > 0$ and
\begin{align}
x^\ast = (A^TA + 2\lambda^\ast I)^{-1}A^Tb \tag{6}
\end{align}
such that $(x^\ast)^T x^\ast = 1$. As a result, $\nabla L(x^\ast, \lambda^\ast) = 0$.

From Fact 1, we need to find $\lambda > 0$ such that
$x = (A^TA + 2\lambda I)^{-1}A^Tb$ satisfying $x^Tx = 1$, equivalently,
we need to find $\lambda > 0$ such that $g(\lambda) = 0$ where
$$g(\lambda) = [(A^TA + 2\lambda I)^{-1}A^Tb]^T[(A^TA + 2\lambda I)^{-1}A^Tb] - 1.$$

*References*

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujpgV.png) Boyd and Vandenberghe, "Convex optimization".
http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

exercise 3.14 (page 115)
[image]

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: For $\lambda > 0$, let
$$g(\lambda) = [(A^TA + 2\lambda I)^{-1}A^Tb]^T[(A^TA + 2\lambda I)^{-1}A^Tb] - 1.$$
Clearly, $g(+\infty) = - 1$. By using the property of the Moore-Penrose inverse [2]
$$A^{+} = \lim_{\delta \searrow 0}  (A^TA + \delta I)^{-1}A^T,$$
we have $\lim\limits_{\lambda \searrow 0} g(\lambda) = (A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b - 1 > 0$.
Thus, there exists $\lambda^\ast > 0$ such that $g(\lambda^\ast) = 0$.
The desired result follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "otherwise $x^\ast = A^{+}b$ is the solution"? Isn't that the solution in all cases? I'm confused as to why you've said "otherwise" here.

Comment: @ThePointer   It means that if $(A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b \le 1$, then $A^{+}b$ is the solution to the problem.

Comment: But why is that undesirable? Why do we assume that $(A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b > 1$?

Comment: @ThePointer Without the constraint $x^Tx \le 1$, the solution is $A^{+}b$. Now with the constraint $x^Tx \le 1$, if $(A^{+}b)^T(A^{+}b)\le 1$, clearly, $A^{+}b$ is the solution. We only need to consider the case $(A^{+}b)^T(A^{+}b) > 1$. Actually, it is nothing but the paragraph just after (4.24) in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ThePointer   I did not write it clearly. I will edit it soon.

Comment: Can you please explain how $L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda (x^Tx - 1)$ is an affine function?

Comment: @ThePointer   When $x$ is fixed, it is the form of $a\lambda + b$ for constant $a, b$.

Comment: @ThePointer  $\lambda (x^Tx-1)$ may not be viewed as a penalty function. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585712/merit-function-vs-largrange-functions-vs-penalty-funcitons

Comment: And how did you conclude that $\lim\limits_{\lambda \searrow 0} g(\lambda) = (A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b - 1$ is $> 0$ at the end?

Comment: @ThePointer  Since $(A^TA + 2\lambda I)^{-1}A^T \to A^{+}$ as $\lambda \to 0+$, we have $g(\lambda) \to (A^{+}b)^T(A^Tb) - 1$. Also, with the assumption $(A^{+}b)^T(A^Tb) >1$, we have $g(\lambda) > 0$.

Comment: Oh, right; we assumed that $(A^{+}b)^TA^{+}b > 1$ at the beginning. This was an excellent explanation -- particularly because it used Boyd and Vandenberghe, which I am also currently studying.

Comment: @ThePointer  Well, it is a nice book for convex optimization, especially the exercises are nice.

Answer (score 1):

Having the sufficient regularity on $f(x), g(x)$, the Lagrangian stated as

$$
L(x,\lambda) = f(x)+\lambda g(x)
$$

is used to determine the stationary points of

$$
\min(\max) f(x)\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ g(x) = 0
$$

those points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \cases{\partial_x f(x) +\lambda\partial_x g(x)=0\\
g(x)=0}
$$

In the present case we have $g(x) = x^{\dagger}x\le 1$ then to handle this restriction with the lagrangian method, as $g(x)$ is no more an equation, we need to introduce a slack variable to transform the inequality into an equation so we augment the lagrangian to

$$
L(x,\lambda,\epsilon) = f(x) +\lambda(x^{\dagger}x-1+\epsilon^2)
$$

and the stationary conditions are now

$$
\nabla L = \cases{A^{\dagger}(A x-b) +2\lambda x=0\\
x^{\dagger}x-1+\epsilon^2=0\\
\lambda\epsilon=0}
$$

here, the last condition $\lambda\epsilon=0$ tell us that if $\lambda \ne 0$ the stationary point is internal/external to the set $x^{\dagger}x\lt1$ and if $\epsilon = 0$ the stationary point is at the boundary, or in $x^{\dagger}x=1$ then if the solution for

$$
A^{\dagger}(A \bar x-b)=0
$$

is such that

$$
\bar x^{\dagger}\bar x\lt 1
$$

we are done because $A^{\dagger}A\ge 0$ otherwise we should follow with

$$
\min(\max)f(x)\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ x^{\dagger} x= 1
$$

NOTE

Now supposing $A$ is $m\times n$ with $m\ge n$
considering $U, V$ such that

$$
A = U\Sigma V^{\dagger},\ \ U^{\dagger}U=I,\ \ V^{\dagger}V = V V^{\dagger}=I
$$

with

$$
\Sigma = \mbox{diag}\left(\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n\right),\ \ \ \sigma_1\ge\cdots\ge \sigma_n\ge 0
$$

we have the equivalent problem

$$
\min ||\Sigma y-c||^2\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ ||y||^2_2=1,\ \ \{y = V^{\dagger}x,\ c=U^{\dagger}b\}
$$

with lagrangian

$$
L(y,\lambda) = ||\Sigma y-c||^2_2+\lambda(||y||_2^2-1)
$$

with

$$
\left(\Sigma^2+\lambda I\right)\bar y = \Sigma c
$$

and

$$
\bar y_k = \frac{\sigma_kc_k}{\sigma_k^2+\lambda}
$$

and after substitution

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{\sigma_kc_k}{\sigma_k^2+\lambda}\right)^2-1=0
$$

here $\lambda^*$ can be obtained with an iterative method like Newton's.
Follows a MATHEMATICA script which handles the $\lambda=0$(internal solution) and $\epsilon=0$ (boundary solution) cases.

```
m = 5;
n = 3;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n}];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m];
X = Table[Subscript[x, k], {k, 1, n}];
solx = Solve[Transpose[A].(A.X - b) == 0, X];
fact = X.X < 1 /. solx;
If[fact[[1]], Print["Internal solution"]; Print[X /. solx], Print["Boundary Solution"]]
If[Not[fact[[1]]], {U, Sigma, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
c = Transpose[U].b;
sigma = Join[Table[Sigma[[k, k]], {k, 1, n}], Table[0, {m - n}]];
y = Table[sigma[[k]] c[[k]]/(sigma[[k]]^2 + lambda), {k, 1, m}];
sols = Quiet@Solve[y.y == 1, lambda, Reals];
y0 = y /. sols // N;
X0 = Union[Table[V.Take[y0[[k]], {1, n}], {k, 1, Length[y0]}]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "regularity"?

Comment: Considering the classical Lagrange multipliers technique, the involved functions should be differentiable.

Comment: So "regular" just means that the functions are differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about neural networks the large weights size can be a root cause of an unstable learning process. To prevent the increasing of the weights magnitude some constraint can be imposed. Popular choice is to use the max-norm constraint of all weights in the layer: $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} < c$.

Here is the citation from the popular paper [Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf): *...Though large momentum and learning rate speed up learning,  they sometimes cause thenetwork weights to grow very large.  To prevent this, we can use max-norm regularization.This constrains the norm of the vector of incoming weights at each hidden unit to be boundby a constant c...*